# How do I install Python Pandas?

Tags: python

I'm trying to install Pandas (python package) on Ubuntu. I can't find it in the repos. Is there a package repo for this or do I have to install from source?

Comment: Ensure you're getting the most up to date version of pandas (the one in the repo is 0.7 whilst the latest stable is 0.13.1).

Answer (score 57):

I'm taking python class, professor suggests us to install in this way, pip is much better than setuptools and easy_install

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install numpy
sudo pip install pandas
```

Comment: This is definitely better.

Comment: Do note that numpy docs state that a pip installed numpy might be slower than one that was apt-get installed.

Comment: This method can install the latest pandas version (0.18.0) in ubuntu 14.04.4

Answer (score 31):

The solution with easy_install didn't install properly on a Ubuntu 12.04 system, while

```
sudo apt-get install python-pandas
```

did a proper install.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this will install the *much* older version 0.7 of pandas was bundled in 12.04 (the current version is 0.13.1).

Comment: I just did this on ubuntu 14.04, but when I run `# python -c 'import pandas;'`  I get
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named pandas

Comment: It turns out that `apt-get install` installs pandas into `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas` which was not on my python path. To check the python path I used `python -c 'import sys; print sys.path;'`.  The working import is `python -c 'import sys; sys.path.append("/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"); import pandas as pd;'`

Comment: on ubuntu 18.04, if you prefer python3, simply do : `sudo apt-get install python3-pandas`

Answer (score 12):

It's in the [Python package index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas/0.4.3) - use `easy_install` or `pip`.

```
sudo aptitude install python-setuptools # installs easy_install for your python version
sudo easy_install pandas
```

Replace `aptitude` with `apt-get` if your version doesn't have aptitude installed, or use `synaptic` or whatever package manager your version has installed by default.

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo pip3 install pandas
```

This will install the latest version of pandas for Python 3 whereas apt-get does not.

Comment: `sudo` and `--user`? O.o

Comment: you just need to install pip3 command first, with "sudo apt install python3-pip".

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method to install pandas, which can be done *without sudo*, is to use [Anaconda](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/):

- Download the linux build continuum website: http://continuum.io/downloads
- Run the file and follow the installation instructions:

  ```
  bash Anaconda-1.9.1-Linux-x86_64.sh  # file may have different version numbers
  ```

This will install python and pandas (and lots of other modules) in an anaconda directory in home (by default).

You can update to the latest version of pandas (along with other modules) using conda:

```
conda update pandas
```

*You can also create virtual environments and other useful things...*

The problem this solves, over pip, is that there are issues in software dependencies of some modules (scipy especially is tricky) or versions compiled against an incorrect version of numpy.

It's useful to be on the latest version for bug-fixes and performance enhancements! [A **lot** has changed](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html) since version 0.7 (which is the version packaged in 12.04).

Answer (score 0):

To install through > bash Anaconda.. you need to have bzip2 installed

```
sudo apt-get install bzip2
```

then follow [Hayd's suggested procedure](https://askubuntu.com/a/426847/301560)

Also make sure to install it on your home dir (*without root*) and to source .bashrc so you do not have to open a new session as requested

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

then proceed with

```
conda update pandas
```

Hope that helps!